# Google Cloud Storage API latency

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

We have own MariaDB server on one server in the Google Compute Engine. One DB table contains blobs about 10kB - 1.5MB, these blobs are INSERT, SELECT only, no UPDATE, DELETE rarely. The table takes about 100GB and is growing. We would like to move it out of the DB, so have just tried to store a few blobs in the Google Storage.

But a simple benchmark showed that reading the blobs using Python `google-api-python-client` (and `httplib2shim`) by `objects().get_media()` is much slower than connection to our MariaDB server: **400ms vs. 10ms**. The OAuth2 requires an extra HTTP request, so I would expect the total time about 20ms, not 400ms. The new Python library `google-cloud-storage` `blob.download_as_string` is not faster.

**Update:** when I make the files available for the public download (`http://storage.googleapis.com/...`), then the speed is comparable or even faster than MariaDB.

Are these latencies of the Google Storage API OAuth normal or do I miss something else? Of course, we prefer the secure access to our data, if possible.

Comment: Just a guess, but probably the public storage is on some kind of cdn?

Comment: Nope, just a plain public access to the Google bucket without any CDN.

Comment: @xmedeko did you ever get the speeds down for secured access?

Comment: @dendog Nope, I have used unsecured access for reading.